# Should duplicate closing be based on quality or on time of posting?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Here's a scenario: Suppose there are two persons X and Y, now person X posts a question about topic Z but with a poor title (and poor presentation overall), now some time later (maybe years) , person Y posts the same question with a better title , formatting and overall quality of the question. Let's also say that person Y's question, is the one which can be found more easily by google search/stack exchange search due to a more 'searchable' title to the query.

For the situation above, would it be better to close person X's question as a duplicate of Y or would it be better to close Y's question as a duplicate of X's question?